# How to merge pivot tables in Pandas without duplicates in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a DataFrame imported from a csv file called test_data that's structured like this:

| School Name | Test Score | Students in Grade 11 | Students in Grade 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PS 1 | Advanced | 170 | 106 |
| PS 1 | Basic | 87 | 53 |
| PS 2 | Advanced | 141 | 120 |
| PS 2 | Basic | 168 | 167 |

I wanted the data for each school to be in one row only, so I used .pivot_table() to do this:

```
test_data_by_grade_11 = test_data.pivot_table("Students in Grade 11", ["School Name"], "Test Score")


test_data_by_grade_12 = test_data.pivot_table(("Students in Grade 12", ["School Name"], "Test Score")

test_data_by_grade_11.rename(columns = {"Advanced":"Grade 11 Advanced", "Basic":"Grade 11 Basic"}, inplace = True)

test_data_by_grade_12.rename(columns = {"Advanced":"Grade 12 Advanced", "Basic":"Grade 12 Basic"}, inplace = True)
```

And I successfully got two tables like this with the word "Test Score" above the headers of the table:

| School Name | Grade 11 Advanced | Grade 11 Basic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PS 1 | 170 | 87 |
| PS 2 | 141 | 168 |

| School Name | Grade 12 Advanced | Grade 12 Basic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PS 1 | 106 | 53 |
| PS 2 | 120 | 167 |

I wanted to merge these pivot tables back together to create a table like this:

| School Name | Grade 11 Advanced | Grade 11 Basic | Grade 12 Advanced | Grade 12 Basic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PS 1 | 170 | 87 | 106 | 53 |
| PS 2 | 141 | 168 | 120 | 167 |

However, when I try to merge them, I get really skewed data and duplicates that don't match the .csv file, like this:

| School Name | Grade 11 Advanced | Grade 11 Basic | Grade 12 Advanced | Grade 12 Basic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PS 1 | 170 | 87 | 87 | 105 |
| PS 2 | 170 | 87 | 87 | 136 |
| PS 3 | 170 | 87 | 87 | 85 |
| PS 4 | 170 | 87 | 87 | 96 |

(The Grade 12 Basic values DO exist in the file, but definitely don't match up with the correct rows).

As a result of these duplicates, the output returns almost 5 million rows, whereas the original .csv file has around 6500. Not sure what's going on here or what I'm missing - I suspect it's something to do with the left_on or right_on properties but I've played around with those and haven't gotten the desired table yet.

Comment: There is a typo in your code. The last two line produce syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the final dataframe with just one `.pivot`:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={'Students in Grade 11': 'Grade 11', 'Students in Grade 12': 'Grade 12'})

out = df.pivot(index='School Name', columns='Test Score')
out.columns = [f'{a} {b}' for a, b in out.columns]
print(out.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  School Name  Grade 11 Advanced  Grade 11 Basic  Grade 12 Advanced  Grade 12 Basic
0        PS 1                170              87                106              53
1        PS 2                141             168                120             167
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've tried this but am getting the error "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape." I've heard aggfunc can be used to solve this, but I don't think I need to take the sum or mean of any of the data so I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: @FJJ You can drop the duplicates of use `df.groupby()` and do sum/mean/... Just make sure in column `School Name` you have unique values. Other possibility is to use `.pivot_table` instead `.pivot` with correct `aggfunc=`

Comment: `.pivot_table` worked. That's the only change I made - I didn't need to add an `aggfunc=`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly similar result:

```
df=df.pivot_table(index=['School Name'],columns='Test Score',\
          values=['Students in Grade 11','Students in Grade 12'])
```

#concat column level index name with level 0 index name using list comprehension:

```
df.columns=[(col[0] + '-' + col[1]) for col in df.columns]
```

Finally reset row level index:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```